# iOS 13 nav bar not fitting to content

Tags: swift, ios13

I've encountered an issue with the nav bar in iOS 13 when making it transparent. I have a navigation bar that I show and hide when a view controller appears/disappears.

When I pop the navigation controller and show the navigation bar again the background image and shadow image are not filling all of the nav bar's contents.

As you can see from the image I have search bar in the navigation bar that is derived from a `UISearchController`.

Here is the code for showing/hiding the nav bar:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    public func showTransparentNavigationBar() {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }

    public func hideTransparentNavigationBar() {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    }
}
```

These methods are being called on the `viewDidAppear` of the initial view controller and pushed view controller.

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VinGazoil No, not found a solution. It seems to be a bug in iOS 13 itself as I have seen it happening in other apps

Comment: If this issue is only on iOS 13, would you be able to include a screenshot of the expected output?  I'm having a hard time fully understanding the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `true` in the ViewController that contains the SearchBar.